# How do I deal with a base class with no db table in Fluent Mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement the persistence layer of AspNet Identity using NHibernate, e.g. `UserStore` etc.

I have all the persistence classes, i.e. `UserClaim` mapped. but when I try and run the project, I get an error like:

> Association references unmapped class:
>   Core.AspNet.Identity.NHibernate.IdentityUserClaim

I suspect this is because I declare `public partial class Userclaim : IdentityUserClaim`, but `IdentityUserClaim` isn't supposed to have a table, maybe some sort of null mapping, but I just don't know.

My current mapping looks like:

```
public partial class UserclaimMap : ClassMap<Userclaim>
{
    public UserclaimMap()
    {
        Table("UserClaim");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
        References(x => x.AgentUser).Column("UserId");
        Map(x => x.DateCreated).Column("DateCreated").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DateUpdated).Column("DateUpdated").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ClaimType).Column("ClaimType").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ClaimValue).Column("ClaimValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. could you please post session factory configuration? By default Nhibernate doesnt create table for base class

Comment: By default NHibernate doesn't create any tables, but it is looking for a mapping for the base class. I don't have session factory now, will post later.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use a partial class for mapping, try without the partial class

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican A class being partial makes no difference to how that class works or ends up once compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your User class references this class. You have to tell him that it is actually your UserClaim class.

```
public UserMap()
{
    HasMany<UserClaim>(x => x.Claims);
}
```

Comment: I do, in the use mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>()
  .IgnoreBase<Entity>()
```

in your session factory to ignore base class,

reference : 
[Fluent NHibernate: How to tell it not to map a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858245/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-tell-it-not-to-map-a-base-class)

**Edit:**

I have done a brief test and it seems like if you do not have a class map for the super class NHibernate actually ignores it, I added following classes and maps

```
    public class IdentityUserClaim
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Userclaim : IdentityUserClaim
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual string ClaimType { get; set; }

        public virtual string ClaimValue { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class UserclaimMap : ClassMap<Userclaim>
    {
        public UserclaimMap()
        {
            Table("UserClaim");
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
            Map(x => x.DateCreated).Column("DateCreated").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.DateUpdated).Column("DateUpdated").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ClaimType).Column("ClaimType").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ClaimValue).Column("ClaimValue");
        }
    }
```

and the session factory is,

```
private FluentConfiguration CreateConfiguration(IPersistenceConfigurer configurer)
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(configurer)
                .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Userclaim>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor()));
        }

        private IPersistenceConfigurer CreateTestDatabaseConfiguration()
        {
            return SQLiteConfiguration
                .Standard
                .InMemory()
                .ShowSql();
        }
```

So it looks like the problem is in some other mapping, could be due to a class map referring super class IdentityUserClaim instead of the UserClaim.

Comment: Surely that applies only to auto-mapping?